# php error reporting Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: php, error-reporting

i am doing a stuff in php and not it is debug mode. So i am us

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but When i try to access any character of string it gives me error due to the error reporting.

```
$sentence = "Hello World"; 
$sentence[0]   //Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

edited:

```
public static function prepareSentence($sentence)
{
    $sentence = trim($sentence);
    if ($sentence[0] == '"')  //Uninitialized string offset: 0 
        $sentence = substr($sentence, 1, strlen($sentence));

    if ($sentence[strlen($sentence) - 1] == '"')
        $sentence = substr($sentence, 0, -1);

    if ($sentence[0] == '"' || $sentence[strlen($sentence) - 1] == '"')
        return self::prepareSentence($sentence);
    return $sentence;
}
```

How should I do in order to work in dev mode. I need the  error_reporting(E_ALL);

thanks in advance.

Comment: a little more code would be nice. Do you use the sentence variable before?

Comment: runs just fine: http://ideone.com/R6y3n

Comment: this shouldn't return any errors. Can u give the complete code atleast relevant to this section. As far as i can see, this is fine

Comment: When i echo the $sentence it gives the correct string.

Comment: This works: http://codepad.org/P67h8NrK How are you calling it? I'd personally check to make sure a valid string was provided, and probably use `substr()` or `str_replace()`.

Comment: [`str_replace()` example`](http://codepad.org/NSD7IN57).

Comment: still works fine http://ideone.com/ZVUmr

Comment: And if you don't want to strip `"` within the sentence, you can use [`trim($sentence, '"')`](http://codepad.org/RfgIUm9F)

Comment: I needed to remove from the starting and ending, not from the inside, By the way is there any good approach for that?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For empty string, you can't use `$sentence[0]`, that will cause the notice you got.

You can add `!empty($sentence)` to check if it is empty.

Comment: actually I was parsing bunch of strings from the file. So the file was not empty. There were a lot of string chunks but due to some spaces for the method came null string and gave the error. It is my bad. I just checked and realized. tx.

Comment: The problem with empty is that empty("0") will also return true.

Comment: @KeVin programmatically 0 and empty are different, empty is absence of data while zero is a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating $sentence as a string ($sentence = "Hello World";) and then calling it as an array ($sentence[0]).
That is no longer allowed.
It used to work silently in the background and change the variable to an array for you with that error but as of PHP 7.1 it will fail completely.
Comes out as an E_NOTICE error (should actually be upgraded to E_DEPRECATED or something as it now fails but whatever).

Comment: This is not correct. What happened in PHP 7.1 was that now negative indices was allowed as well: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#example-51

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WordPress and having the same issue, ensure to add `domain-name.tld/wp-login` as your URl redirect